# Ocaml Ctypes-ffi works on utop but has strange behaviour after compilation

Tags: winapi, ocaml, ctypes, ffi

I am new to OCaml, and try to learn the Ctypes FFI.

My code below is working fine from within the `utop` toplevel, but when I try to compile it to native (with `ocamlfind  ocamlopt  -o hello.exe -linkpkg -package ctypes,ctypes.foreign -thread test.ml`), the resulting binary does not execute `VirtualAlloc`.

However, if I move the line `let allocaddress = virtualalloc null 276 12288 64` right after the `VirtualAlloc` binding, the resulting binary works as expected. Evaluating the expressions with `;;` has the same behaviour.

```
open Ctypes

let dll = Dl.dlopen ~filename:"kernel32.dll" ~flags:[]

let virtualalloc =
  Foreign.foreign ~from:dll "VirtualAlloc"
    (ptr void @-> int @-> int @-> int @-> returning int)

let rtlmovememory =
  Foreign.foreign ~from:dll "RtlMoveMemory"
    (int @-> ptr void @-> int @-> returning void)

let allocaddress = virtualalloc null 276 12288 64
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this should be a bug report to  https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/issues

Comment: i  submitted the issue, did u try it and had the same behaviour??

Comment: Nope, I don't have a windows machine. But this definitely looks weird and worthwhile a bug report.